# Problems with jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project in Eclipse, that inculdes some files with data(not in classpath), and I want to pack this project to the runnable jar-file, but the problem is, that after I pack it to the jar, it's not located there. How can i add it to the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an additional source folder and put your files in there.  Unless explicitly told to Eclipse only jars things up in the classpath.

If you cannot do that due to some unmentioned restriction then please revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making sure it's in the src folder.  Eclipse tends to add everything in there into the JAR.  If that's not an option, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actualised your project's content in Eclipse before making the jar?

Right click on package explorer -> refresh.